# AutoHotkey script for automatic windowed-fullscreen on a specific app

Tags: autohotkey

Here's where I'm at :

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode, 3

Loop { ; apparently a loop is recommended for app-as-a-trigger.

  Send, ^!a



WinGet, p_exe, ProcessName, Forged Alliance, Style, Style, A {
if(Style & 0xC40000) {
  WinSet, Style, -0xC40000, A
  WinMaximize, A 

}
Sleep, 100
}
}
return
```

Obviously i'm trying to make it so that when ForgedAlliance.exe runs it's window borders are removed and it is maximised.

i had a working script triggered by a hotkey :

```
LWin & f::

WinGet Style, Style, A
if(Style & 0xC40000) {
  WinSet, Style, -0xC40000, A
  WinMaximize, A 

} else {
  WinSet, Style, +0xC40000, A
  WinRestore, A
}
return
```

and now I wish for it to be triggered by the App running.

I tried :

```
If ProcessExist("ForgedAlliance.exe") {

}
return
```

but that did not work, this condition always returned true (always executed the code) even though FA was not running at targeted anything my mouse hovered.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Where is the code for the `ProcessExist` function?

Comment: Putting an infinite loop in your script is not an ideal replacement for a timer. Please see my answer.

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf  the same code as within the loop in the above function. Both this and fischgeek's suggestion are effective onmouseover of any app, window or menu when the app starts running and therafter. this of course, is not what I want. I want to target only the app who's exe mane or window name matches, no other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you're putting your loop inside of your process check. Which means it will only check for that once. Here is a better solution that uses a timer.

```
#Persistent

procName := "ForgedAlliance.exe"
SetTimer, CheckProc, 2000
Return

CheckProc:
    If (!ProcessExist(procName))
        Return

    WinGet Style, Style, % "ahk_exe " procName
    If (Style & 0xC40000) 
    {
        WinSet, Style, -0xC40000, % "ahk_exe " procName
        WinMaximize, % "ahk_exe " procName
    }
    Return

ProcessExist(exeName)
{
   Process, Exist, %exeName%
   return !!ERRORLEVEL
}
```

Comment: can you explain this code to me? Why are you saying CheckProc and then proc NOT exists. I don't get it. Why would it not existing have any actions? and what is this second part where you call exeName a variable which I do not see initiated anywhere

Comment: in anycase as is the script you provided closes itself instantly.

Comment: Scripts that only contain timers must have the #Persistent directive. That's why it's closing immediately.

Comment: @fischgeek is correct. I had an `#Include` for the `ProcessExist` function which kept mine from closing. I've added `#Persistent` to my answer.

Comment: that did it. Thank you. I threw in a minimize before the maximize so that the window wasn't off center. It only hides the window for a split second. the code is now perfect and exactly what I want, thank you.

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf  what if I'm trying to do this to two processes? procName := "ForgedAlliance.exe" || "HomeworldRM.exe"  ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Process Exist check needs to go inside a timer.

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, CheckForProcess, 100

CheckForProcess:
{
    Process, Exist, ForgedAlliance.exe
    if (ErrorLevel) {
        ; process is running
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: this applies effect to any frame (browser, explorer, apps, menus) underneath cursor when process starts any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: There is nothing in this code (or your code) that is affected by a mouse cursor hover event. My code merely shows you how to check to see if a process is running and trigger an action if so desired when it is. I may not be understanding your ask fully. Can you elaborate? I will be open to moving this to a chat too.